# How to fix "Errors: The key "issuer" has already been defined previously"?

Tags: stellar.toml, error

Ok, so I uploaded the .toml file, figured out SSL and CORS, but I got this error afterwards. There's actually nothing highlighted in red concerning the parsed .toml file, and I have added home domain in Stellar Laboratories. Please help me fix it. Thanks in advance.

From https://aluxhim.tech/.well-known/stellar.toml

```
VERSION="2.0.0"

FEDERATION_SERVER="https://stellarid.io/federation/"

[DOCUMENTATION]
ORG_DBA="Aluxhim"
ORG_NAME="ALUXHIM LTD"
ORG_OFFICIAL_EMAIL="aluxhimt@aluxhim.tech"
ORG_URL="https://aluxhim.tech"
ORG_LOGO="https://i.ibb.co/2gnf23B/20200827-041209-0000-removebg-preview.png"
ORG_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS="London, United Kingdom"
ORG_PHONE_NUMBER="+447565472589"

[[PRINCIPALS]]
email="michaeljehavoh@aluxhim.tech"
name="Michael Jehavoh Aluxhim"
telegram="michaeljaluxhim"

[[CURRENCIES]]
code="AXS"
issuer="GAKQZFRNJ7KPWWLAGFXGV72CWAXQS374WHC7H42WSJXH627AME4O7AXS"
display_decimals="8"
fixed_number="33000000"
image="https://i.ibb.co/2gnf23B/20200827-041209-0000-removebg-preview.png"
issuer="Aluxhim"
name="Aluxhim Sheqel"
status="Live"
is_asset_anchored="false"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I've just realized my mistakes. They're right there: issuer identified twice, status use brackets, is_asset_anchor used brackets and fixed_number used brackets. Hope that helps future inquiries.